# Get FreeSpace Available from a nonexistent Directory Path

Tags: bash, shell

I wanted to get the freespace available from a given path. Currently, my method is by using

`df -kb $PATH | awk 'NR == 2 {print $4}'`.

The problem for the above method is it won't work for a non-existing path.
So, it can be solved by `mkdir -p $PATH`.

But then again, it will create blank directories just to check for free spaces available (provided these path is not exist in the system earlier)

I can run `rmdir $PATH` after running my `df`, but remember? I use `mkdir -p` earlier and the OS may have created a few levels of directories and executing `rmdir $PATH` only manage to remove the last level.

So, any simple solution available just for me to check the free space from a given path(especially for nonexistent path)? or is there any utility that can output the mount point from a given directory path (so that I can just grep the mount path from df to get the available free spaces)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know the space available for a director that you plan to create but does not exist yet, first you need to find the closest parent directory that exists:

```
dir_path=/some/dir
existing_path=$dir_path
while test ! -e $existing_path; do
  existing_path=$(dirname $existing_path)
done
```

then you can `df` on `$existing_path`.  All this in a single bash function:

```
function my_df() {
  existing_path=$1
  while test ! -e $existing_path; do
    existing_path=$(dirname $existing_path)
  done

  df -k $existing_path
}
```

Comment: great 1! like the "recursive" dirname approach. thanks a lot!

Comment: Not exactly recursive, more iterative.  A recursive version would be: `function my_df() { test -e $1 || my_df $(dirname $1); test -e $1 && df -k $1; }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
test -d $dir_path && ( df -k $dir_path | awk 'NR == 2 {print $4}' )
```

Comment: df -k just won't work for a non-existent $dir_path.

`df: ($/appl/asdasd) not a block device, directory or mounted resource`

Comment: Yes, I know that it will not work, this is why I put a test before (`test -d $dir_path`) and the `df` is executed only if the test succeeded (the `&&` bash operator).

Comment: checking disk-space for an existing directory is piece of cake. my goal is actually to check for the disk space for a non-existent $dir_path.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the question.  New answer coming.